# What type of byte do we send with IsoDep.transceive(byte[] data)?

Tags: java, android, nfc

I'm writting an Android app to read a contactless card (SpringCard in Card Emulation mode via my computer) with ISO-DEP protocol.

When I use the IsoDep.transceive(byte[] data) method, I'm always getting an IOException but my contactless card has well received my bytes and send a response (I see it in my card emulation program log).

The question is do I have to send specific format data byte (such as APDU) for the transceiver method ?

```java
package com.example.nfccardreader;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.IsoDep;
import android.nfc.tech.NfcA;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private NfcAdapter mAdapter;
    private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;

    private final byte[] DATA = { 
            (byte) 0xFF,
            (byte) 0xFA
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        resolveIntent(getIntent());
        mAdapter= NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        mPendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    }

     @Override
     protected void onResume() {
         super.onResume();
         mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, null, null);
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPause() {
         super.onPause();
         if (mAdapter != null) {
             mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
         }
     }

     private void resolveIntent(Intent intent) {
         String action= intent.getAction();

        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)){
             Tag tag= intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
             communication(tag);
        } else {
             //log error
        }
     }

     private void communication(Tag tag) {
         byte[] received= null;
         IsoDep card= IsoDep.get(tag);
         try {
             card.connect();
             received= card.transceive(DATA);
         } catch (IOException e) {
             //log error
         } finally {
             try {
                 card.close();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 //log error
             }
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
         setIntent(intent);
         resolveIntent(intent);
     }

}
```

Comment: This post should be helpful:

[Read data from NFC tag (IsoDep)][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815007/read-data-from-nfc-tag-isodep

Comment: This post should be helpful:
[Read data from NFC tag (IsoDep)][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815007/read-data-from-nfc-tag-isodep

Answer (score 1):

There are no restrictions on the format of the byte array you send (and receive) with `IsoDep.transceive()`.

As your tag is an emulated one, it may be a bit slower to respond. You could try increasing the time-out using [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep.html#setTimeout%28int%29).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you have to send APDUs in the transceive() method but it depends on the type of card you emulate.
Try to replace DATA with

```
    public static byte[] GET_RANDOM = { 
        (byte) 0x00, // CLA Class        
        (byte) 0x84, // INS Instruction
        (byte) 0x00, // P1  Parameter 1
        (byte) 0x00, // P2  Parameter 2
        (byte) 0x08  // LE  maximal number of bytes expected in result
    };
```

If the emulated card is compliant with [ISO 14443](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_14443), this will return a random data. Emulated cards are often slow to respond. You can try to read it with an android application like [NFC TagInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.nfctaginfo) to check if it works well.

Comment: thanks, my emulated card is ended ISO 14443 compliant.

Comment: -1 ISO/IEC 14443-4 transport protocol (ISO-DEP) does not imply support for/requirement of ISO/IEC 7816-4 APDUs. At least the NXP chipset and NFC stack do not require the use of APDUs on top of ISO-DEP (I have no information about the Broadcom chip/NFC stack though).

Comment: Yes, apologies, I mingled 7816 and 14443. By the way, I don't see when we have to use other thing that APDU's to communicate with a springcard in emulation mode.