# ADPU command for selecting an app from a calypso card

Tags: java, nfc, javacard

I'm using android studio and i'm trying to select an app from a smart card before reading data using NFC.
When i'm trying to select the app it's just throws an exception and the result I get back changes every time but looks like that "[B@41bf9ca8".

```
            byte[] SELECT = {
                (byte) 0x00, // CLA Class
                (byte) 0xA4, // INS Instruction
                (byte) 0x04, // P1  Parameter 1
                (byte) 0x00, // P2  Parameter 2
                (byte) 0x08, // Length
                (byte) 0x31,  (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0x49, (byte) 0x43, (byte) 0x2e,
                (byte)0x49, (byte) 0x43, (byte) 0x41, // AID 315449432e494341
        };
        byte[] result = tag.transceive(SELECT);
        if (!(result[0] == (byte) 0x90 && result[1] == (byte) 0x00)) {
            throw new IOException("could not select applet");
        }
```

Is there anything wrong with my SELECT command?

Comment: do a byte array to hex string output. that will give the response from the card as to why it is not working. but the other problem is that the first bytes will not be 0x90, 0x00. Data goes there, the LAST 2 are 0x90 and 0x00

Comment: what is your status bytes for you Get_STRING? your exceptions that you throw are not useful because they don't output what the status byte is. That will give much more information as to what is wrong and will be a much better help. Also when you edit and want to call me out, add a comment and type @Robert Snyder so that I get notified

Comment: Also A4 is a SELECT instruction. You are probably wanting the Get Data instruction. which could be B0 or B1. What documentation are you basing this command off of?

Comment: @RobertSnyder I found an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815007/read-data-from-nfc-tag-isodep?lq=1 . I'm sorry but what do you mean by status bytes? and btw I changed the instruction to B0 and I still get an exception.

Comment: 2 things. First is The program you got this from used `04` and not `A4` for the Get_String command. Second is you should find a copy of ISO7816-4. There are a few floating around on the web. Look at Section 5.1. Table 1 shows how those commands are built, and what the response is going to be. The "Response trailer" is 2 bytes and described as "Status bytes denoted as SW1-SW2" It is the response from the card to your command, and always follows the data sent from the card.

Comment: Please don't make this into a debug session. The idea to use the last two bytes as status word is correct (the SELECT with P2 = 0x00 returns data in addition to a status word). This should be put as an answer, not as an edit followed by *another* question. You can retrieve back your answer by looking the edits of the question.